# trouble with variable in awk match command

Tags: bash, awk

Apologies if below is messy or there's a cleaner way to do it, I'm still learning!

I'm using CURL to grab a page with numbers/HTML in, to get to the table with numbers I'm using the below command

```
echo $curlo | awk '/<th>00/ { match($0, /<th>00/); print substr($0, RSTART - 10, RLENGTH + 40000); }' | sed 's/d1ffce/\'$'\n/g'| sed 's/88ff7f/\'$'\n/g' | grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

To begin the output at th00, print the next 40000 characters (the page varies in size but will never be that high), replace some hex colour codes and then print out all the numbers only

However th00 will change to th01, 02 etc with the hour so I'm trying to use a variable. For testing I set cnt=00 and replace it in the command with the variable

```
echo $curlo | awk '"/<th>$cnt/" { match($0, "/<th>$cnt/"); print substr($0, RSTART - 10, RLENGTH + 40000); }' | sed 's/d1ffce/\'$'\n/g'| sed 's/88ff7f/\'$'\n/g' | grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

but the output is completely different. If I echo $cnt it's printing 00 fine. I've also tried placing the whole th00 in the cnt variable and the same issue.

For comparison when I use the first command, I get 382 lines, when I use the second I get 896

This is using bash shell btw

Comment: Why do you need `RLENGTH+40000`? If you just want to print the rest of the string, leave out the argument and it defaults to printing until the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell variables aren't expanded inside single quotes. But it's better to assign an awk variable with the `-v` option:

```
echo "$curlo" | awk -v cnt=$cnt 'match($0, "<th>" cnt "") { 
                    str = substr($0, RSTART-10, RLENGTH+40000);
                    gsub("d1ffce|88ff7f", "$\n", str);
                    gsub(/^[^0-9]+|[^0-9]+$/, "", str);
                    gsub(/[^0-9]+/, "\n", str);
                    print str; }'
```

There's also no need to pipe to `sed` and `grep -o`, since `awk` can do the same things with `gsub()`.

Comment: thanks! I ended up doing the job another way but for the sake of learning to do it properly I'll give this a go when I get home.